# My function in python returns 0 if i give an input variable to the function

Tags: python

Today i decided to learn some python, tried to do a random choice picker just to train and did it good, but unfortunately i made a function for the choice picker, and made an variable to pick how many choices there is and requests input for it, but something doesnt work out. Let me give you an example of what i mean:

```
def choices(num):
    if num == 3:
        randchoicez = [input("What is the first choice? "), input("What is the second choice? "),
                       input("What is the third choice? ")]
        rndchoices = random.choice([1, 2, 3])
        if rndchoices == 1:
            print(randchoicez[0])
        if rndchoices == 2:
            print(randchoicez[1])
        if rndchoices == 3:
            print(randchoicez[2])

    elif num == 2:
        randchoices = [input("What is the first choice? "), input("What is the second choice? ")]
        rndchoice = random.choice([1, 2])
        if rndchoice == 1:
            print(randchoices[0])
        if rndchoice == 2:
            print(randchoices[1])


print("Hello and welcome to the random  choice program. ")
print("How many choices? (Can be up to 5 and start from 2) ")
nr_choices = input()

choices(nr_choices)
```

if i call the function 'choices' with a number that you pick its gonna return 0 and do nothing

```
choices(nr_choices)
```

but if i call it with a number like 2 like this:

```
choices(2)
```

its gonna work.

This is what happens when i run the script with the choices(nr_choices)

[image: this is what happens when i run the script.]

Comment: where you written the code to return the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're expecting `num` to be a number in the function but `input()` returns a string.

So change your input line to:

```
nr_choices = int(input())
```

Which would make `nr_choices` a number.